# Kinesis ProvisionedThroughputExceededException even after sufficient shards

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-kinesis

We have been facing ProvisionedThroughputExceededException issue while writing data on Kinesis stream.

**Case 1:**
We were using single m4.4xlarge (16 core, 64GB mem) instance to write data on stream pass 3k request from Jmeter, EC2 instance provides us 1100 request per second, So we chose 2 shard stream(i.e. 2000 eps).
In result we were able to write data on stream successfully without any loss.

**Case 2:**
For further testing we had created 10 EC2 m4.4xlarge (16 core, 64GB mem) cluster and 11 shard streams (based on simple calculation 1000eps for one shard, so 10 shard + 1 provision).
When we tested that EC2 cluster with different request cases from Jmeter like 3, 10, 30 millions. We received ProvisionedThroughputExceededException error on our log file.

On Jmeter side EC2 cluster provides us 7500eps and i believe with 7500eps stream having 11000eps capacity should not return such error.

Could you help me to understand reason behind this issue.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like Kinesis is not hashing/distributing your data evenly across your shards - some are "hot" (getting the `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException`), while others are "cold".

To solve this, I recommend

1. Use the `ExplicitHashKey` parameter in order to have control over which shards your data goes to. The [PutRecords documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecords.html) has some basic info on this (but not as much as it should).
2. Also, make sure that your shards are evenly split across the hash space (appropriate starting/ending hash key).

The simplest pattern is just to have a single pre-defined ExplicitHashKey for each shard, and have your PutRecords logic just iterate through it for each record - perfectly even distribution. In any case, make sure your record hashing algorithm will distribute records evenly across the shards.

Another alternative/extension based on using ExplicitHashKey is to have a subset of your hashspace dedicated to "overflow" shard(s) - in your case, 1 specific ExplicitHashKey value mapped to one shard - when you start being throttled on your normal shards, send the records there for retry.

Answer (score 0):

Check your producer side, are you sure you are inserting data to different shards? "PartitionKey" value in PutRecordRequest call may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass different "Partition Keys" for records to share data between different "Shards".
Even if you have created multiple Shards and all of your records use the same partition key then you're still writing to a single shard, because they'll all have the same hash value. Check-out more here [PartitionKey](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html#API_PutRecord_RequestSyntax)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when working with a kinesis stream created with a `single shard`. The action I was trying to do is do a `kinesis read` via .Net SDK

At first I tried to change stream mode from `provision` to `Ondemand` when creating the stream as below and it did not work/help

```
  FunctionTestStream:
      Type: AWS::Kinesis::Stream
      Properties:
        Name: FunctionTestStream
        RetentionPeriodHours: !Ref KinesisRetentionPeriodHours
        StreamModeDetails:
          StreamMode: "ON_DEMAND"
```

When I searched for the data entry in AWS kinesis Data Viewer UI, I specified shard and time stamp that I knew the record must have been inserted in the stream and found the data entry. Otherwise with wrong time stamp, the data entry was not being found.

This made me realize that my code in .net sdk could be referencing the wrong time stamp, and reading attempt would occur multiple times until the throttle or reading threshold exceeded, thus resulting to the error - `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException, Rate exceeded for Shard`. I changed Timestamp from `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1)` to `DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1)` since my usecase estimates that the application will try to perform a read to a kinesis 1 minute late after it has been written. This helped solve the problem

```
    GetShardIteratorResponse getShardIteratorResponse = await _kinesisClient.GetShardIteratorAsync(new GetShardIteratorRequest
    {
        StreamName = streamName,
        ShardId = shard.ShardId,
        ShardIteratorType = ShardIteratorType.AT_TIMESTAMP,
        Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1)
    });
```